# MIB design from scratch

Tags: snmp, mib

I need to design MIB for SNMP analysis from scratch. I mean, we got an OID for our enterprise on the tree 2.25 now it's time to code.

However, I can't get an example of this. When looking under /usr/share/snmp/mibs directory on our Linux machine a see a lot of files (for example: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt, IF-MIB.txt, etc). I understand that these files follow a format for MIB, but I just not getting it because they import some things that are completely strange to me.

For example:

```
IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Counter32, Gauge32, Counter64,
    Integer32, TimeTicks, mib-2,
    NOTIFICATION-TYPE                        FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    TEXTUAL-CONVENTION, DisplayString,
    PhysAddress, TruthValue, RowStatus,
    TimeStamp, AutonomousType, TestAndIncr   FROM SNMPv2-TC
    MODULE-COMPLIANCE, OBJECT-GROUP,
    NOTIFICATION-GROUP                       FROM SNMPv2-CONF
    snmpTraps                                FROM SNMPv2-MIB
    IANAifType                               FROM IANAifType-MIB;
```

Then, in every import file I see more imports and more imports. Can somebody tell me what is the top most file for that or point me in any direction faq or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go back to its IETF RFC document,

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578.txt

Comment: Well, it's the only option, I guess.

Comment: If you are writing a MIB compiler like me, you may have a chance to look deeper, but even in that case, it is not easy to fully understand them all. :) It is never a SIMPLE protocol.

Comment: Lex Li, do you you use SNMP4j for that?

Comment: No. I am the author of #SNMP, which contains a MIB compiler, http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com